# dplyr left_join() by rownames

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using the `dplyrs` function `left_join` to combine two data.frames.

Now I would like to manually join them by using the `rownames` in the left data.frame and the appropriate column name in the right data.frame of `left_join`, but I get the error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "dplyr::left_join(x.tsummary, sto.info,
>   by = c(rownames(x.tsummary) ="

My code

```
> dplyr::left_join(x.tsummary, sto.info, by = c(rownames(x.tsummary) = 'Symbol'))
```

Is this even possible? In the documentation it says that I should specify column names, but it would be great if I could join on rownames for the left data.frame.

Comment: Did you try `==` ? Double equal to sign. Just curious. May not be the answer because you have to specify column names. Another suggestion would be to transpose your data rows to columns and then do a left join.

Comment: Hadley is against the `row.names` concept. I doubt it is possible without an hack, but why can't you just create a new variable using `dplyr::add_rownames` and then join?

Comment: I didn't know the add_rownames existed. Thank you!

Comment: Here is more detail about [why row names are not supported](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#rownames) in `dplyr`: 1) storing row names differently than the rest of the data is a bad idea and also requires a new set of tools to work with them; 2) often rows cannot be identified by a single string; 3) row names cannot be duplicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this help?

```
dplyr::left_join(x.tsummary %>%
                                    mutate(Symbol = rownames(x.tsummary)),
                                 sto.info,
                                 by = 'Symbol')
```

Comment: It is sufficient as an answer I suppose :)

Answer (score 20):

`dplyr` now recommends to use `tibble::rownames_to_column`
(`dplyr` also has a function `add_rownames`, which is deprecated in favor of `tibble::rownames_to_column`).  For example:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
left_join(rownames_to_column(x.tsummary), sto.info, by=c("rowname" = "Symbol"))
```

Comment: I think that in this example `rownames` should be `rowname and `by = ("rownames" = "Symbol"` should be `by = c("rownames" = "Symbol"`