# How to combine matrices by rowname and insert empty space in non-matching elements in R?

Tags: r, matrix, match

I want to combine two matrices with partly overlapping rownames in R. When the rownames match, values from the two matrices should end up as adjacent columns. When the rownames only occur in one matrix, empty space should be inserted for the other matrix.

Data set:

```
testm1 <- cbind("est"=c(1.5,1.2,0.7,4.0), "lci"=c(1.1,0.9,0.5,0.9), "hci"=c(2.0,1.7,0.8,9.0))
rownames(testm1) <- c("BadFood","NoActivity","NoSunlight","NoWater")
testm1 #Factors associated with becoming sick
testm2 <- cbind("est"=c(3.0,2.0,0.9,7.0), "lci"=c(1.3,1.2,0.2,2.0), "hci"=c(5.0,3.1,1.7,9.0))
rownames(testm2) <- c("BadFood","NoActivity","Genetics","Age")
testm2 #Factors associated with dying
```

Desired output:

```
           Sick        Dying
           est lci hci est lci hci
BadFood    1.5 1.1 2.0 3.0 1.3 5.0
NoActivity 1.2 0.9 1.7 2.0 1.2 3.1
NoSunlight 0.7 0.5 0.8 -   -   -
NoWater    4.0 0.9 9.0 -   -   -
Genetics   -   -   -   0.9 0.2 1.7
Age        -   -   -   7.0 2.0 9.0
```

Is there a simple way to do this that would work for all matrices?

Comment: Bummed out about the "-1". Too simple question to ask on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method that keeps everything in matrix form:

```
# get rownames of new matrix
newNames <- union(rownames(testm1), rownames(testm2))
# construct new matrix
newMat <- matrix(NA, length(newNames), 2*ncol(testm2),
                 dimnames=list(c(newNames), rep(colnames(testm1), 2)))
# fill in new matrix
newMat[match(rownames(testm1), newNames), 1:ncol(testm1)] <- testm1
newMat[match(rownames(testm2), newNames), (ncol(testm1)+1):ncol(newMat)] <- testm2
```

In the final two lines, `match` is used to find the proper row indices by row name.

This returns

```
newMat
           est lci hci est lci hci
BadFood    1.5 1.1 2.0 3.0 1.3 5.0
NoActivity 1.2 0.9 1.7 2.0 1.2 3.1
NoSunlight 0.7 0.5 0.8  NA  NA  NA
NoWater    4.0 0.9 9.0  NA  NA  NA
Genetics    NA  NA  NA 0.9 0.2 1.7
Age         NA  NA  NA 7.0 2.0 9.0
```

Comment: Gave "accept" to this, because it did everything that I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you are after though its not that pretty and requires the data to be a data.frame not a matrix. Hope it helps at least ! 
( Code was adapted from this question & answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34530141/4651564 )

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 <- as.data.frame(testm1)
dat2 <- as.data.frame(testm2)
full_join(   dat1 %>% mutate(Symbol = rownames(dat1)  ),
             dat2 %>% mutate(Symbol = rownames(dat2)  ),
             by = 'Symbol')
```

Comment: This solution seems neat, but the "full_join" function was not found on my computer, despite installing dplyr. Did that code work for you when you ran it?

Comment: Which version of dplyr do you have installed?  ```full_join``` was added in version 0.4.0  January 9, 2015  [ref](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/01/09/dplyr-0-4-0/)

Comment: Ahhh, that explains it. Had version 0.2 installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using merge() function.
First of all cast your test matrices into dataframes, then use merge on the dataframes, finally convert the result in a matrix (but do you necessarily need a matrix?).
Here's an example code:

```
testm1 <- as.data.frame(testm1)
testm2 <- as.data.frame(testm2)
result <- merge(testm1, testm2, by='row.names', all.x=T, all.y=T)
# all.x is needed if you want to save rows not matched in the merge process
result <- as.matrix(result)
```

If you want to obtain a data frame, simply omit the last line of code. Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. The only issue is that the order of rows is a bit messy

Comment: Yes, I assumed the order of the rows is not important... you can change row order working with the arguments of the function. But you have reason , I should have thought it before:)